# How to design this?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing a registration screen.Here I need to place the button on circular image bottom corner,this is my output and I am using 3rd party library from github **de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0**
Now I want to place camera bottom  on bottom- right corner of image view 
[image: Output]
Need Output
[image: Needed Output]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.this_pc.framelayout.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:contentDescription="Image Border"
                android:padding="0dp"/>

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/round_border"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:background="@drawable/camera"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: so whats is your problem now ?

Comment: I  want to put that camera button on imageview like new whats aap profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this...

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/uploadImage"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="//define according to your layout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="//define according to your layout"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_Image"
                    android:background="@drawable/camera" />
```